# "I think that ..." v.s. "From my viewpoint/perspective"?

Tags: word-choice

When I am asked "why you believe this candidate is or is not ready for ...",

shall I use

> "I think that the candidate is ready ...",

or

> "From my perspective, this candidate is ready ...

Comment: I'd get rid of the "that". It's not needed. "I think the candidate is ready" is all you need, if you choose "think" rather than "From my perspective . . .."

Comment: Hi! Please let me know what you think of my answer.  I'd be happy to clarify anything if you need me to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are **the same.**  You can use whichever one you would like.

"Perspective" is:

> A particular attitude toward or way of regarding something; a point of view. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/perspective)]

*I will define "thought" instead of "think" so both definitions are for nouns.*  A "thought" is:

> An idea or opinion produced by thinking, or occurring suddenly in the mind. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/thought)]

These are obviously *very similar.*  Both options ("from my perspective" and "I think that") are **grammatical, but "I think that" is *much* more prevalent [[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+think+that%2Cfrom+my+perspective%2CI+believe+that&corpus=26&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20think%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20my%20perspective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20believe%20that%3B%2Cc0)].**

*Note: I included "I believe that" in the Ngram because it is another applicable phrase (in case if you want an extra one).*

Answer (score 0):

For most everyday purposes, there is no difference, but strictly speaking, and taking these formulations at face value, there is.

*I think* only means that you have this particular thought; the formulation, considered by itself does not imply anything, about whether and how this thought is related to any other thoughts you may have. For all that this formulation tells us, it is possible that this is an isolated thought that has just popped up in your mind, but it is also possible that it is a result of careful reasoning.

*From my perspective*, on the other hand, implies that there is some perspective, i.e. some wider body of beliefs, attitudes, commitments, etc. that you have, and that this thought stems from that perspective.

Moreover, *from my perspective*, typically carries somewhat relativist implications, that is, one's use *from my perspective* normally implies an acknowledgement that from somebody else's perspective, the things may look different.